# Best practice for detecting enemy death in 3D platformer

Tags: collision-detection, platformer

I'm building a 3D platformer, and I'm having issues figuring out how I should determine whether the player has effectively jumped on an enemy to kill them.

My current approach uses "hurtboxes" above the enemies like so:

[image: hitbox picture]

And if the player has a negative velocity and isn't grounded while they collide with that hurtbox, it will kill the enemy. This works pretty well, but isn't ideal because the hurtbox being too big makes killing them easy, but making it too small results in unexpected failure to kill the enemy, which would be frustrating to a player.

Is this typically how 3D platformers deal with this issue, or are there better ways?

Comment: This screenshot appears to be from the Unity engine, but you did not tag this question as Unity. Does that mean that you want a general answer which can be applied with any technology stack, or would a Unity-specific answer suffice?

Comment: What is it about using a large hurtbox that makes it too easy? Maybe there's an important game design decision that needs to be made that can keep the larger (more reliable) hitboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ground detection empty object parented to the player, you can use this,

Do A box cast from ground detection like this,

```
Collider enymyHitInfo  = Physics.BoxCast(origin , size , angle , direction);
```

and if the collider is true and the colliding object has "Enemy" tag then you can Destroy gameobject, like this ,

```
if(enymyHitInfo.collider != null)
{
     if(enymyHitInfo.collider.gameObject.Comparetag("Enemy))
  {
      Destroy(enymyHitInfo.collider.gameObject);
  }
}
```

This is all assuming this is C# and unity the same would apply to any other language but the syntax changes. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a Unity-specific answer. The question author did not reply to my inquiry if a Unity-specific answer suffices, but I assume it does because the screenshot is from Unity.*

When players and enemies got rigidbodies, then you can implement [`OnCollisionEnter(Collision)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

In this case you probably don't need a separate hitbox, because the [Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html)-object passed to the function contains a lot of useful data about how exactly the collision happened. The most interesting for this case are perhaps the [contact points](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.GetContacts.html). You can check if the point coordinates are on top or on the side of the enemy. You can also check the directions the contact normals are facing. What works best depends on what collider shapes you are using for the player and the enemies.

Comment: How would you go about checking if the contact point is on the top or side of the enemy? This could be really useful for me.

Comment: I'd recommend making the player and enemies interact via trigger colliders, rather than collisions. The reason is that quite often you want these kind of stomped-on enemies to stop existing when they're stomped (or at least change state), and bounce the player off of them. If they interact by collision, then by the time we get the message, the physics engine has already modified the player's velocity to resolve the collision, so when we add our bounce on top of that, we can get inconsistent behaviour - depending on how the collision got resolved. But triggers let us have full velocity control.

Comment: @DMGregory On the other hand, using rigidbodies allows you to let Unity handle the bouncing physics, which you can tune via physics materials.

Comment: Yeah, my experience with that has not given consistent platformer-style bounces, unfortunately. You'll often want to be able to explicitly control the bounce height after a stomp - say to enforce certain level design metrics and control the difficulty of the jumps. If the bounce height varies continuously based on incident velocity, as the physics engine will simulate, then it becomes more challenging to get a consistent platforming game feel.